# SSL Error in NextJS 13 App when running in Docker, but not when running directly

Tags: docker, go, ssl, next.js

When attempting to run a Golang backend and NextJS 13 frontend app with Docker, getting a SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG error, despite the app functioning well with HTTPS and self-signed certificates on a local machine without dockerizing.

With docker on https://127.0.0.1:3000/ I get an error

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:3000. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

With **http**: http://127.0.0.1:3000/ frontend part will run, but not connecting with backend and giving a server error while backend is still running on https and works as needed in docker.

I've been struggling for a few days now, and any assistance or guidance to help resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/backend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

frontend.dockerfile

```
FROM node:21-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:21-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY --from=build /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /app/public ./public

COPY --from=build /app/certificates/localhost-key.pem ./certificates/
COPY --from=build /app/certificates/localhost.pem ./certificates/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

backend.dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.21 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY backend/go.mod backend/go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY backend/ .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main ./server.go

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

COPY --from=build /app/main .
COPY --from=build /app/config config/
COPY --from=build /app/logger logger/
COPY --from=build /app/pkg/database/media pkg/database/media/
COPY tls/ /tls/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./main"]
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone' 
}

module.exports = {
  ...nextConfig, 
  images: {
    domains: ['127.0.0.1'], 
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https', 
        hostname: 'i.ibb.co', 
        port: '', 
        pathname: '**', 
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https', 
        hostname: '127.0.0.1', 
        port: '', 
        pathname: '/**', 
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: *"With docker on `https://127.0.0.1:3000/` I get an error ... With http: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` frontend part will run"* - this means there is no SSL on port 3000 and that's why you get the SSL error.  Unfortunately nothing is known about your actual code, config of the servers and what the intended design of your setup is, so it is impossible to say what you actually need to fix here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added next.config.js to the description, if I need to add something else please tell what it is. It's simple nextjs 13.5 application and I want to dockerize it with certs for using https. I think that issue is with docker image or creating that throught compose file. It works with certs with https without docerization and works also in docker but just with http. Somewhere in between creating the image, copying certs and then running the frontend, the self signed certificates are not trusted anymore by browser, not sure why.

Comment: *"the self signed certificates are not trusted anymore by browser"* - this has nothing to do with the certificates. There simply is no HTTPS on port 3000, only plain HTTP.

Comment: "There simply is no HTTPS on port 3000, only plain HTTP" on the docker side then, while it works without docker with https, just running npm run dev for frontend. When I run docker: docker compose build, docker compose up -d frontend, docker compose up -d backend and then go to https:// 127.0.0.1:3000/ it's not working.

@SteffenUllrich where should I look or what should I do to debug it and fix it? To understand where the issue is? How you could start debugging it?